# How to change the background color of a saved transparent bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, transparency

I am opening a png image into a Bitmap, making some modifications to it and then saving it to disk as a jpg.  In the case where the png has some transparent areas, they are saved as black.  Is there a way to change this default behavior so the image is saved with a  different color background such as white?

Thanks

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You could draw it to a new bitmap, e.g.

```
   Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), 
    image.getHeight(), image.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0F, 0F, null);
```

then save new bitmap instead

Comment: When I am saving canvas image... background color I am getting black. Any other way to change.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Any way to change the black background color?

Comment: @RahulBaradia you can check my answer it might help you.

Comment: @Homen you can check my answer it might help you.

Answer (score 9):

To save an image and retain its transparent areas you can't save it as JPG, you have to save it as PNG, and not only that, but setting the setting of `setHasAlpha()` to true **BEFORE** saving the image, so it would be like that:

before saving:

```
mBitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
```

And when saving, save the image as PNG using whatever the method you are using for saving, for example:

```
File file = new File(folderDir, name);
try {
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
mBitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: Yes my issue was saving as JPEG instead of PNG.  Thank you!

Comment: @Grux great that my answer could help you

Comment: Thanks man, you just saved my day.. this answer was really helpful..

Comment: @KalpeshKundanani my pleasure :))

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin you can use this Extension function

```
/**
 * Returns a new Bitmap with provided background color and recycles the current one.
 */
fun Bitmap.changeBackgroundColor(color: Int): Bitmap {
    val newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config)
    val canvas = Canvas(newBitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(color)
    canvas.drawBitmap(this, 0F, 0F, null)
    recycle()
    return newBitmap
}
```