# Saving Signature Capture as jpg

Tags: mono, xamarin.android

I am using following for capturing signature on my application

https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MonoDroid.CaptureSignature

Its working fine if i save image as png but i want to save it in jpg

I changed Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png to Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpg

but what i am getting is a black jpg file because the writing is in black

and the background is already black. How can i make image background white?

code i changed

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(extFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
  _capture.CanvasBitmap().Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpg, 100, fs);
}
```

Looking for help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only do this by setting the color on a Canvas.

See [How to change the background color of a saved transparent bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572564/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-saved-transparent-bitmap)

So you could try changing:

```
_capture.CanvasBitmap().Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, fs);
```

to something like:

```
var b = _capture.CanvasBitmap();
var newBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(b.Width, b.Height, b.Config);
var canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
canvas.DrawColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.DrawBitmap(b, 0, 0, null);
newBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpg, 100, fs);
```

But this code is untested here - sorry!

Comment: untested but works great. Thanks Stuart
Only thing i had to change was
var newBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(b.Width, b.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);