# Bitmap background is black color. Need to make it white

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm making a bitmap and the background color is black. How can I make the background as white ?

```
        File filesDir = context.getFilesDir();
        signFile = new File(filesDir, name + ".jpg");

        os = new FileOutputStream(signFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
```

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4573564/991085

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to do the same.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null); is showing error. Im making bitmap from OutputStream. See the code in my question.